# How to add 'Hosts' as a seperate row despite information being displayed on same table as users

Tags: sql, sql-server

In our DB structure, we have Users. Within this table it is stated whether the user is a host or not. This is through a field 'IsHost' (boolean). I want to run a query that shows users who are not hosts in one row (Visitors) and another row which states the name of the host for the visit.

I'll copy in the Select and From parts of the query to help you out.

```
SELECT  [User].FirstName + [User].LastName AS 'Visitors Name',
        User.FirstName + User.LastName AS 'Host Name',
        Company.Name AS 'Company Name',
        VUT.AutoCheckoutTime, 
        VUD.ExpectedTime AS 'Expected Time on Site'
FROM  [User] 
INNER JOIN VisitUser ON [User].UserId = VisitUser.UserId 
INNER JOIN Visit ON VisitUser.VisitId = Visit.VisitId 
INNER JOIN VisitUserType VUT ON [User].DefaultVisitUserTypeId = VUT.VisitUserTypeId 
                            AND VisitUser.VisitUserTypeId = VUT.VisitUserTypeId 
INNER JOIN VisitUserDate VUD ON VisitUser.VisitUserId = VUD.VisitUserId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Company ON [User].CompanyId = Company.CompanyId
```

Answer (score 0):

S'okay, remembered how to do this. Added
`hostuser.FirstName + ' ' + hostuser.lastname [Main Host],` to SELECT and

```
Visituser hostvisituser on Visit.VisitId = hostvisituser.VisitId 
                        and hostvisituser.IsMainHost = 1             
LEFT JOIN [User] hostuser on hostvisituser.UserId = hostuser.UserId
```

to FROM. Cheers if anyone viewed anyway